# BoundaryCallback for PagedList never gets called

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-architecture

I've created a Room Database on my device, which returns

```
// The Int type parameter tells Room to use a PositionalDataSource object.
@Query("SELECT * FROM Word ORDER BY id")
abstract fun getByFactory(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Word>
```

This factory call is then used in my repository, where I connect it with my boundaryCallback

```
val boundaryCallback = MyBoundaryCallback()
return wordDao.getByFactory().toLiveData(
   pageSize = 20,
   boundaryCallback = boundaryCallback
)
```

My boundary callback is basic and looks like that

```
class MyBoundaryCallback() : PagedList.BoundaryCallback<Word>() {

    val int = 0;

    @MainThread
    override fun onItemAtFrontLoaded(itemAtFront: Word) {
        Timber.d("hello")
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
        Timber.d("hello")
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd: Word) {
        Timber.d("hello")
    }
}
```

The problem is that, although my datasource (room database) doesn't contain any entries, the boundary callbacks don't get called.
Do you have any clues what could be the problem?